# Writing a set of first order clauses to define a predicate

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I need some help on where to begin with the following question:

> We say that a **list (term)** represents the natural number $k$ in binary if it consists of constants 0 and 1 and the digits of the binary expansion of $k$ are listed in reverse order. For example both the lists $[1,0,1,1]$ and $[1,0,1,1,0,0]$ represent the number $13$ (written *backwards* in binary), as $13=1+4+8$; the lists $[\ ]$, $[0]$, and $[0,0,0]$ represent $0$, etc.
>
> Write a set of first-order clauses $\Sigma$ that define a predicate $INC(x,y)$ in such a way that $INC(t,s)$ is entailed by $\Sigma$ whenever $t$ and $s$ are list representations of natural numbers in binary and the value represented by $s$ is one bigger than the value represented by $t$.

Would I begin defining some way to write (in first order logic) that $s$ is a larger number than $t$, and that $s,t \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What does $\mathbb{R}$ have anything to do with this?

Comment: My bad, it should have been $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Still it's not clear what your list is. What can you do with them? Is it using Godel numbering?